# Jenkins. Error when copying secret file to my workspace during build

Tags: jenkins, copy, credentials

While running, my pipeline is duplicating the binaries located in a BitBucket workspace into the build workspace, then needs to add in the build workspace some secret files from the credential store, and then start to build the docker image.

But the pipeline is failing when copying the files.
I searched and applied different solutions found here but still have the same error.

Running the following command :

```
stage('push credential in jenkins workspace') {
      steps {

        script {
          withCredentials([
              file(credentialsId: 'saremediation', variable: 'SA_KEY_PATH')]){
              sh "ls -al"
              sh "mkdir ${CERTIFDIR}"
              sh "cp ${SA_KEY_PATH} ${CERTIFDIR}/credent.json"
              
              }
        }

      }
    }
```

failed with the following error :

```
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [SA_KEY_PATH]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ cp **** server/src/configuration/certificats/credent.json 
cp: target 'server/src/configuration/certificats/credent.json' is not a directory
```

the CERTIFDIR folder is well created, because when I add `sh "ls -al ${CERTIFDIR}"`, I cans see that the folder is created and empty.

Answer (score 3):

fix the problem by applyong this syntax in the cp command

```
sh "cp \"${SA_KEY_PATH}\" \"${CERTIFDIR}\""
```